# What exactly are the benefits of Spark over Mapreduce if I'm doing a batch processing?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, mapreduce, bigdata

I know Spark has in memory capability that is very useful for iterative jobs. But what if my requirement is traditional batch processing ETL. Does Spark provide me any benefit there? Please give all the pointers related to this, it will help me a lot.

1. How does Spark help me in case there are no iterative work and it's a batch process?
2. Is there any scenario where MapReduce would perform better than Spark? Any scenario where MR will be better than Spark?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know Map Reduce, then consider:

- writing Word Counting in MR when you need to list the top N words. Far more work over multiple Steps in MR vs. 7 or 8 lines in Spark.
- for those with dimension processing a la dimensional model, a lot easier to do in Spark.
- Spark Structured Streaming use cases...

Certain tasks with extreme high amounts of data may well be better using MR if you cannot acquire enough hardware or Cloud compute resources, i.e. writing to disk and processing per functional step.